# Text of label in CustomUITableView is not changing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I use below code to change text of the lable of my custom `uitableviewcell`:

```
   override func  tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //NSArray *allsubviews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LICustomUI" owner:nil options:nil];
    //LIMerchantTableViewCell *cell = [allsubviews objectAtIndex:LIApplicationLayout() == LIApplicationDirectionRightToLeft ? 8 : 9];

    let allSubViews = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LICustomUI", owner: nil, options: nil)

    var cell:LIInsuranceNameTableViewCell = allSubViews[11] as! LIInsuranceNameTableViewCell

    cell.insuranceName.text = "Hello"

    println(cell.insuranceName)

    cell.insuranceName.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();

   // cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();

    return cell
}
```

the result of the `println()` log is:

```
<UILabel: 0x7ad71930; frame = (0 11; 320 21); text = 'Hello'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7ad71a10>>
```

but in the device (emulator) the text is not changed!

Comment: what text do you see on device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using storyboards, make sure you have connected the label to the `insuranceName` outlet (if you haven't, just control-drag from the label to the outlet you find within the Assistant inspector).

Also, use `println(cell.insuranceName.text)`, and not just `println(cell.insuranceName)`.

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your code from below.
1. Register the nib in viewDidLoad
2. deque in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerNib( UINib(nibName:"nibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "identifier");
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell;
        let subViews     = myTableCell.contentView.subviews as! Array
        if subViews.count > 0 {
            if let myLabel = subViews[0] as! UILabel {
                myLabel.text = "All good to go";
            }

        }
    }
```